# How to call another shell script within AWK

Tags: shell-script, awk, hp-ux

I wish to call another shell script **tm.sh** within AWK. I'm trying as below but its not working as no error during executing this command but output doesn't display that I coded into **tm.sh**. please help me.

```
bdf | awk '{if($5>90 && $6=="/u05") {(exec "/u05/bkpscript/tm.sh") }}'
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `system()` function:

```
awk '{printf("%s ",$1); system("d2h " $2)}' file
```

Comment: i am not able to call another script from system() command.

Comment: @Jhonsamuel in that case, there's either something wrong with your input data (no lines match the 2 conditions you set) or something wrong with your script. We can't help you if you don't show your data and the script.